# Joining Tables in Python

Tags: python, sql

I need to replicate below SQL query in Python and get the results in python.

```
select a.customer_id as custid_tab1,  a.country_id as ctryid_tab1, b.customer_id_tab2 as custid_tab2,  b.country_id_tab2 as ctryid_tab2, c.customer_id_tab3 as custid_tab3,  c.country_id_tab3 as ctryid_tab3
    from table1 a
    left join table2 b
    on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
    left join table3 c
    on a.customer_id=c.customer_id
    where b.customer_id is null
    and c.customer_id is null

table1  
customer_id country_id
101         5
102         5
103         5
104         5
105         5
106         5
107         5
108         5
109         5
110         5

table2  
customer_id country_id
101         5
102         5
104         5
105         5
106         5
108         5
109         5
110         5

table3  
customer_id country_id
101         5
103         5
104         5
105         5
106         5
107         5
110         5

Final output                    
customer_id_tab1    country_id_tab1 customer_id_tab2    country_id_tab2 customer_id_tab3    country_id_tab3
101                    5               101               5                  101                 5
104                    5               104               5                  104                 5
105                    5               105               5                  105                 5
106                    5               106               5                  106                 5
110                    5               110               5                  110                 5
```

Above output has been obtained using the above SQL code. Now I need to get the same output in Python.

Please help!

Kind Regards,
Srikanth

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL, the first steps would be to import the necessary library which is [PyMySQL](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='password', db='database_name', autocommit=True)
query = 'your_entire_query_to_be_inserted_here'
```

Now, you can read the results of your query using a library called [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql(query, db)
```

This should give you your result.

Comment: But, I am actually want to join tables using python script itself. Is that something which you can help with please?

Comment: Refer to this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html